# SASS Syntax Error: Properties aren't allowed at the root of a document

Tags: sass

I am using SASS and it has been working, but now I get this...

```
Syntax error on line 1: Properties aren't allowed at the root of a document.
```

My file is using variables in the SASS format.

```
$blue-muted: #222244
$red-muted: #442222
$green-muted: #224422
```

When I remove the variables (and replace the values with the actual colors), it compiles fine.  What is wrong here?

EDIT: My confusion stemmed from having installed HAML 3.0, but getting behavior consistent with an early 2.0 version.  It turned out that I had a SASS command line tool from an old version in my path and it was running instead of the current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the new SCSS syntax which should look like:

`$blue-muted: #222244;`

if you want to use sass, the colors should be declared as:

`!blue-muted = #222244`

Comment: You are right - I also had to remove the dash, since they are not allowed in that syntax.  Thanks.

Comment: edited question because I was unknowingly running an older version than I thought.